# How to retrofit cruise-control on Peugeot?

Tags: peugeot, cruise-control

I tried to retrofit the cruise control on a 307cc (2007) but for some reason it fails to activate even when I am diving with correct speed and gear (4+).

- activate cruise control on BSI
- not able to locate where is the ECU option on DiagBox ?
- stalk mounted, car recognize it and displays `CC---`, on off seems to work and if I try to use it while the speed is too low it will display a message on the screen.

  Still, it does fail to activate when it is suppose to work, giving no message.

Comment: Props for getting it to work at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, here are two problems I had to fix

1. The ECU option is the one after the BSI one, it doesn't have ECU in its name, just a code.
2. If your cruise control stick does not have speed limit, do not activate it on BSI or in ECU.

   Does anyone knows how to trick the limit to allow it to work in 3rd gear under 35mph?